# WebGet adds trailing slash inappropriately

Tags: wcf, rest, dynamic, client, parameter-passing

I have a rest client which tries to call http://my-server/section1/section2?param1=foo

http://my-server/section1/section2?param1=foo
http://my-server/sectionX/sectionY?param2=bar
http://my-server/sectionA/sectionC?param3=kuku

notice that the query parameters key name changes (param1, param2,param3...)

The contract I implemented is

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
        [OperationContract]
        Message MyMethod();
```

However this will cause the actual uri called to be:
http://my-server/section1/section2/?param1=foo

Note that a trailing slash has been added between section2 and ?

Does someone know how to prevent it?

David

PS
pls note that 
1) a the trick of taking the last segment+ the parameters as a parameter to MyMethod (and usage of UriTemplate="/{lastSegment}) will cause the question mark (?) to be decoded... 
which will ruin the call request
2) removing the UriTemplate completely will cause the methodname to be part of the uri...

Answer (score 2):

You really should not use WCF contracts on the client to make calls to REST services.  Simply use HTTPWebRequest or HttpClient to make those calls.